# MongoDB & ASP.NET MVC: Where to specify database name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am trying to run MongoDB with my Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC 5 project. My question is: how do I tell Visual Studio the name of the database that I want to use?

So far, I have the following in the `<appSettings>` of `Web.config`:

```
<add key="DbName" value="db1" />
```

Then, I run the `mongod` command to start MongoDB, and then run the Visual Studio debugger. It shows me a page I have written which allows me to register a user, which should create some entries in the database. However, when I go to the MongoDB shell by running `mongo`, and type in `show dbs`, I get the following:

```
ASPNETDB 0.078GB
admin (empty)
local 0.078GB
```

And there is no sign of the `db1` database I specified before.

Please can someone explain where how I specify the name of the database I want to use?

Comment: Mongo does not have Tables, it has Collections!

Answer (score 0):

that is normal specified in the `web.config` file under `connectionStrings` like

```
<add name="MongoHQ"
     connectionString="mongodb://<user>:<pwd>@<host>:<port>/<collection>" />
```

and then using MongoDB drivers you can easily connect as

```
var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionStringFromConfig).GetDatabase("your_db");
```

but you can find [all documentation in mongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/)